# Declaring interfaces in separate files

Tags: typescript

Say I have a file user.ts that has the following declaration:

```
export interface User {
  userName: string;
}
```

I want to import this interface from another ts script, but since JavaScript doesn't support interfaces the transpiler wouldn't produce the user.js and I'm getting an error on import.

Of course, I could declare User as a class as a workaround, but is there a way to declare an interface in a separate TypeScript file?

Comment: what extension does the user file have? it should be .d.ts for pure interface files.

Comment: Mine had just .ts. Will try with d.ts, thanks.

Comment: Update. The interface can be located in a separate file like user.ts.  I was using SystemJS to load and transpile my code.  The problem I had was caused by the fact that SystemJS didn't know that the generated empty user.js was meant to be used as a module. After adding the following in the SystemJS configuration the code started working fine:

meta: {
        'user.ts': {
          format: 'es6'
        }

Answer (score 13):

You can try making the user file have the **.d.ts** extension.

For example:

*user.d.ts*

```js
export interface User {
    name: string
}
```

and you can import it as usual:

*someotherfile.ts*

```js
import {User} from './user';
    
function check(user: User) {
    if (user.name) {
        console.log('yeey works');
    }
}

check({ name: 'ion' });
```

Comment: This code works fine when I use tsc on the command line. But in my app I'm using SystemJS loader that transpiles the code on the fly.  It gives me the following error:

(program):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: uhm. could you update your question with the SystemJS configuration you are using? :)

Comment: Actually the problem seem to be somewhere else :(  
I got your example working with SystemJS as well.

The thing is that I'm using this code in the Angular 2 application, which doesn't like the export keyword. Let me research a bit more.

Thank you for your help!